# How to implement specific functionality in a custom text object in pyQt?

Tags: qt, pyqt, text-editor, qtextedit, mathml

I need to implement a specific text object in QEdit PyQt. I need rich objects that will content special information, capture the keyboard arrow keys only when cursor text is on these objects. They need support selection and copy / paste operations also. Outside of them, the cursor must act as normal behavior. At this time, the object does not need to show images or svg etc. Is only for capture text cursor purposes and to store specific information related with the object.

I read that I can implement a customized text object with this example:
[textobject.py](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/examples/richtext/textobject/textobject.py)

but the example does not contain information about implement new html tags, how to capture focus, etc.

My questions are:

1. How can I add a new html tag related with my custom object for loading and saving documents?
2. How can I detect when text cursor is on the custom object to modify keyboard cursor behavior?
3. PyQt documentation says:

   > "Copy and Paste operations ignore custom text objects."
   >   So is no way to implement copy / paste functionality?
4. How can I access to my custom object content?
   I want to have specifics methods to navigate within the information contained in the object. I could save this information in another object, but I need to synchronize the information with the cursor because a document can contain many of these objects.

Context for my application: I'm developping a very specific application for blind users. I am blind myself. I need to make very specifics customizations to the Richttext area for accessibility. The goal is to develop an accessible math equation editor. For this, I need to add support for mathMl tag. I will process mathMl content inside these tags in my custom object, this part is already implemented at basic level without using any GUI framework. At this time I don't need to show the equation in the screen, I let to screen readers interact with my editor via a COM object. At this time, the equation box is functional, but I need to integrate this functionality in a rich text area. the idea is, a document can contain N math expressions that can be read, modified and saved in a document.
I plan to implement accessibility for sighted people also in the equation editor, but it is beyond my skills and is not a priority right now.

Also I need to accessibilize tables in rich text area, currently tables are not accesible in QT. Then I think to extend qt table functionality. Style elements like headings etc, does not exist in pyQt. OK, you can write a paragraph with heading style, but screen readers can't detect it. So I need to develop this functionality. I could solve it with customized objects I think.

Currently it need to work in windows only. Maybe later I'll consider other platforms.

I started to program in pyQt yesterday, but I already read a lot of documentation. I wrote a basic rich text editor to test my requirements.

I already tried to implement this application with wxPython phoenix because I've been using WX for a long time. But I couldn't implement custom text objects and I didn't find documentation about it.

If pyQt is limited for my requirements, could you recoment another gui framework?
Y could consider another languages, I chose Python because Python has many math tools like sympy or numpy, and implement user scripting functionality in the app is very easy.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: This question is massively off-topic for SO. It is far too broad, contains multiple questions, and it also asks for software recommendations. Please read the guidance on [ask].

Comment: Your goal is not easy to reach. I think the right direction to start digging (within Qt) would be [QAbstractTextDocumentLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttextdocumentlayout.html). But beware that it is quite a sacred knowledge - it seems within open source domain only people from KDE actually [used that](https://community.kde.org/Calligra/Building/2#Latest_Stable_Version). I tried to do advanced text processing with `QTextDocument` myself in the past but gave up in the end and switched to `QtWebKit` (now deprecated in favour of `QtWebEngine`) and solution with HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: I know this solution.Do you still want to know it?

Comment: Hi, I solved it using different approach. I don't liked it but was a functional solution. Now I planning to develop another progect with similar requirements in editing features, so I'd be glad to hear your answer!
Thank you.